# Open Graph protocol should be integrated

Tags: feature-request, facebook, integration, semantics

In order for a better experience when sharing a link over Facebook (and not only there) it would be nice to have the [Open Graph protocol](http://ogp.me/) in a page.

For example for https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/:

```html
<meta property="og:title" content="Bicycles - Stack Exchange"/>
<meta property="og:type" content="forum"/>
<meta property="og:url" content="https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/"/>
<meta property="og:image" content="http://cdn.sstatic.net/bicycles/img/logo.png?v=123"/>
<meta property="og:site_name" content="Bicycles - Stack Exchange"/>
<meta property="og:description"
      content="Q&A for people who build and repair bicycles, 
               people who train cycling, or commute on bicycles"/>
```

Comment: I think it's worth pointing out that Open Graph is (well, at least appears to be) [an independent standard](http://ogp.me/) for web page metadata, not something proprietary that Facebook is trying to push on other websites.

Comment: Is it worth making all the pages bigger and therefore slower to load for this?  Every network packet has an effect to display time.

Comment: @David Zaslavsky hence the `and not only there` part :) - but nevertheless, I changed the link url.

Comment: that's... quite a lot of extra data to have on a page considering it will be useful for maybe 0.0001% of requests....?

Comment: @Marc Gravell it's just an example, title and image would do the trick as well, but nothing at all??

Comment: @MarcGravell The above metadata is 495 bytes. According to Chrome, a download of http://bicycles.stackexchange.com with all assets is 307k. That's only a 0.16% difference! And it would be useful to more than just facebook: any site that wants have a richer link would benefit.

Comment: @evil I think you'd need to compare a question page, not the homepage.

Comment: @JeffAtwood I used that page because the above metadata was for it. But for example this question page is currently at 176K transfered, so it's still a _tiny_ piece of data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My question would be... to add what? Most of that data is already available via regular html, and it doesn't do too badly:

[image: facebook]

adding an image... well, that's interesting because we *do* do that for apple-touch etc:

```
<link rel="apple-touch-icon"
    href="/content/stackoverflowmeta/img/apple-touch-icon.png">
```

so it wouldn't seem reasonable to advertise the logo that we share on stackauth:

[image: logo]

(or possibly the first image in the markdown? defaulting to site logo?)

but the rest seems a bit redundant? Of course, there is a reasonable number of iOS users, where-as facebook links would be much rarer. I wonder if there is any way to detect if the caller might be *interested* in the open-graph data, i.e. add it when it might help (so: for facebook's servers calling us)

Edit: and here's bicycles:

[image]

Which *could* potentially have additionally the logo:

[image: bicycles]

Comment: not really Mark, at least the one I used: http://www.balexandre.com/temp/2011-09-08_1148.png It shows nothing regarding the link, that's why I started this Meta Question.

Comment: @balexandre then your facebook is broken; I'm adding the image I get...

Comment: I *would* like to see the logo for each site. Looks much nicer. I think it's worth putting some effort in making SE Facebook links look good

Comment: I think it's a bad idea to expect everyone who wants to make a rich link to a SE site to code their own parser. If SE supports OG, then people can just make their linker work automatically without any effort on their part.

Comment: @Marc: [My duplicate question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/176454/incorrect-icon-used-by-facebook-when-pasting-links) demonstrates that FB, when it doesn't have a hint from SE, chooses inappropriate images. (It also got some more attention than this question.) In light of this change in behaviour, I'd invite you to reconsider this decision.

Answer (score 1):

I don’t know when it happened, but Stack Exchange sites now [use](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/247207/193139) the Open Graph vocabulary.

[Previously](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/219847/193139) specified in HTML5 meta tags, which was invalid, but [at some time after 2014-02](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/219847/open-graph-meta-tags-not-as-per-specification#comment711721_219853) via RDFa.

This very question, for example, uses RDFa in the `head` (I have removed the unrelated HTML5 and Microdata attributes):

```html
<meta property="og:type" content="website" />
<meta property="og:image" content="/content/stackexchangemeta/img/apple-touch-icon@2.png?v=c34d758b103d" />
<meta property="og:title" content="Open Graph protocol should be integrated" />
<meta property="og:description" content="In order for a better experience when sharing a link over Facebook (and not only there) it would be nice to have the open graph protocol in a page for example for http://bicycles.stackexchange.com..." />
<meta property="og:url" content="https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/105487/open-graph-protocol-should-be-integrated"/>
```

As they don’t define the prefix `og`, the [RDFa Core Initial Context](http://www.w3.org/2011/rdfa-context/rdfa-1.1) gets used where `og` has the URI `http://ogp.me/ns#`, so it’s the Open Graph protocol.