# Open graph meta tags not as per specification

Tags: bug, status-declined

The Open Graph meta tags in all stackoverflow network websites are not strictly as per the [Open Graph specification](http://ogp.me/). The specification says that it should be in this format:

```
<meta property="" content="" />
```

while currently across stackoverflow network websites it is in this format:

```
<meta name="" content="" />
```

Though it does parse well with FB, but makes sense to correct for all Open Graph parsers to get it right. Here's a current (as on Feb 6, 2014) snippet of Open Graph meta tags from [meta.stackoverflow.com](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/) itself for reference:

```
<meta name="og:type" content="website" />
<meta name="og:image" content="/content/stackoverflowmeta/img/apple-touch-icon@2.png?v=22bf083906e2"/>
<meta name="og:title" content="Meta Stack Overflow" />
<meta name="og:description" content="Q&amp;A for meta-discussion of the Stack Exchange family of Q&amp;A websites" />
<meta name="og:url" content="https://meta.stackoverflow.com/"/>
```

Answer (score 5):

Open Graph, as specced, [is not compatible with HTML5](http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/meta.name.html).  `name` is valid HTML5 and it works, so we're okay not conforming to the specification here.  Using `name`, even if it were valid when we deployed this, is not valid for `og:` strictly speaking, or `twitter:` for that matter.  Meta extensions are an actual approved thing by the W3C.

The OpenGraph specification needs an update, and has for a very long time.

Edit: I had to go find links here, but there's also the issue that Facebook seems to have no real interest in making open graph valid with HTML.  We wouldn't need a namespace for validation if their proposal for [meta extensions](http://wiki.whatwg.org/wiki/MetaExtensions) was completed and accepted...but so far they don't even have a completed proposal, after *years*.

Comment: It’s valid to use the `property` attribute in HTML5. RDFa [extends](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/55133/17633) HTML5.

Comment: @unor this wasn't the case back when it was deployed - we can take a look at changing it later but it's certainly not a priority.  To be strictly correct we'd have to add a lang attribute which I'm also reluctant to do.  Our goal was not "support open graph", it's "minimal possible correct code to make facebook embeds work"

Comment: It's fine if "minimal possible correct code to make facebook embeds work" was the goal. However in today's open web scenario, there are many parsers that rely on open standards and specs. Though the FB parser is liberal, others might not be.